# libreoffice file->New overlays File menu

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

Ubuntu 12.04, I have a dual screen setup, left laptop screen (1st monitor), right 24 inch display (2nd monitor)

When I position Libreoffice in the top left corner of the 2nd monitor and go into the file menu, the dropdowns of New, Recent documents etc are overlaid over my file menu instead of being put to the right.

See screenshot http://twitpic.com/abfcaw

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/952325.

It might help to install the extension that integrates LibreOffice with the global menu. Input `sudo apt-get install lo-menubar` into a terminal.